# Database search with Lucene.net and how to update the index

Tags: sql-server, lucene.net

I have a SQL server database, with about 40 tables that need to be searched. I just started looking into Lucene for .net. These tables that need to be searched doesn't have any column that identifies when the row was last updated or created. We don't want to change the table structure right now. What are the options I have to identify if a row in a table has modified so that I can update the document in the Lucene index? And same for newly created rows too. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't tell what has changed by looking at the database, then just assume all of the rows have changed and update them all in Lucene.  That handles your new rows as well.

If this is too slow or time consuming, then that gives you a reason why you should change your table structure to store the last updated date.